# When gravatar is not loaded the "title" text is displayed in sidebar - Google Chrome browser

Tags: bug, design, google-chrome, sidebar

In the chat room section placeholder for the side bar, if any of the user's gravatar is not loaded, the `title` text is displayed inside the box, it contains the user name along with when was he/she last active on that chat room in Google Chrome browser.

In that case, the UI is not looking good, so when the user's gravatar is not loaded, restrict to show the `title` in the screen.

Screenshot with element inspection in Google Chrome:

> [image: Chat room box]

In Mozilla Firefox for the same case, the UI is not break. It is displaying as below:

> [image: Firefox]

In Google Chrome:

> [image: Chrome]

**Configuration:**
Google Chrome: Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Not something doable by the backend. It's a browser feature.

Comment: Maybe there's only title attribute without alt attribute? If so, it's SO fault, otherwise, browser fault.